# Can I see Tranquility Base and other lunar landing sites on Google Map's moon charts?

Tags: the-moon, nasa, landing-site

I'm trying to find the location of the Apollo program landings on [Google Map's Luna charts](https://www.google.be/maps/space/moon), but while I can find roughly the location of the Apollo 11 landing site, I don't appear to be able to see the actual Lunar Module and other human indicators. I did find a specific site that has been blurred, but I'm not sure if that's the actual landing site. And I haven't looked for any other Lunar landing sites.

Can I even see these sites along with the remains left by humans?

Answer (score 9):

Yes you can, here's a screencap from the online Google Luna Chart.

[image: [on google luna map online]]

But it is **much** easier to find in Google Earth, which shows coordinates, and nice guide flags for interesting locations, etc.

[image: [on google earth pro]]